# Google analytics - Tracking events that happened in the past

Tags: logging, google-analytics, tracking

Let us say I have a log file that has events that happened in the past. Now for some reason suppose that I am not able to track those events in real time using GA but want to do it at a later point of time using some kind of batch processing. Can I somehow add those events to GA and also keep the original time the event occurred.

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0):

I would say probably not given the way in which GA is implemented in most cases.  Also, having a quick look at the API for Google Analytics (http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/) nothing jumps out.  You might be able to use a different approach, however, where you use the Data Export API in combination with the results of your log parser and mash the metrics together in that way.

Certainly if you come across any alternative approaches, I would be keen to hear about it them.

Cheers,
Damon.